# Check if an access database (.mbd) exists if not create it

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc, .net-4.5

I am using ODBC to create some tables in a Microsoft Access Database (lets call the database users.mdb).

I would like to be able to run a check before hand though to see if the database exists in the first place. If it does not I want to create it.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I am using C# and .NET4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (!File.Exists(mdbPath))
    CreateAccessDatabase(mdbPath);
```

Comment: Wow I swear sometimes the simplest solutions evade me... You would not believe some of the convoluted ways of doing this I have attempted! Thank you!